# If table returns 0 rows then select another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

As my query will return 0 rows sometimes then I need to select another statement if it returns 0 rows.

```
select MR.NAME as NAMES,Isnull(cast(sum(MTTR/Month(getdate())) as decimal(18,2)),0) as YTDCURRENTYEAR from #Meantimeresult as MR 
 where YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Month)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Month)) <= MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    group by MR.NAMES
```

2nd statement is

```
Select NAME='' ,YTDCURRENTYEAR=0
```

Comment: If your query executed by some code (c#, vb, f#, java etc.) this kind of task can be done by the code in much more simpler way.

Comment: @Srikanth . . . You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.  There is likely a simpler way to write the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your first query with a common table expression and use union all:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT MR.NAME as NAMES, Isnull(cast(sum(MTTR/Month(getdate())) as decimal(18,2)),0) as YTDCURRENTYEAR 
    FROM #Meantimeresult as MR 
    WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Month)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + Month)) <= MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    GROUP BY MR.NAMES
)

SELECT Names, YTDCURRENTYEAR
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME='' ,YTDCURRENTYEAR=0
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CTE
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (YOUR FIRST QUERY)
   BEGIN
      YOUR SECOND QUERY
   END
```